# How can i Minimize a program or application using command prompt

Tags: cmd.exe

I've tried

```
cd ..\
cd ..\
cd ..\
cd program files
cd keys2xinput
START  keys2xinput.exe 
/min keys2xinput.exe
```

the minimize does not work!!

I think I need a way to modify applications using cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done natively using command prompt. However you can use [**NirCmd**](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html). As written in [its manpage,](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html#win) the command to minimize windows or running programs is:

```
nircmd win min [find] [window to find] [Additional Parameters]
```

For example, to minimize all open notepad.exe windows:

```
nircmd win min process "notepad.exe"
```

Download [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.zip)(x32) or [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd-x64.zip)(x64) And then extract and open command prompt in the directory. Then run the above command.

Comment: Thanks. I spent 2 hours looking or how to do it